# JavaFX tableview resize to fit window

Tags: javafx, tableview, fxml, borderpane, gridpane

I am just trying out JavaFX and am forcing my way into it because it is suppose to be the future.  I am trying to create a table with 4 columns.  The columns AND THE TABLE should resize to fill the parent pane.  I cannot for the life of me get this to work.  I have been trying for over 4 hours now and the tableview does not resize.

Here is my FXML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import t.cubed.fxml.*?>


<BorderPane styleClass="root" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="t.cubed.fxml.FXMLDocumentController">
    <top>
        <MenuBar fx:id="menuBar" styleClass="menu-bar">
        <menus>
            <Menu text="File">
                <items>
                    <MenuItem onAction="#handleOpenAction" text="Open" />
                    <MenuItem onAction="#handleExitAction" text="Exit" />
                </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu text="Edit">
                <items>
                    <MenuItem onAction="#handleWeightAction" text="Edit Weights" />  
                    <MenuItem onAction="#handleFilterAction" text="Edit Filters" />
                    <MenuItem onAction="#handleOptionsAction" text="Options" />
                </items>
            </Menu>
        </menus>
    </MenuBar>
    </top>
    <center>
        <GridPane>
               <!--
               <padding>
                   <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0"/> 
               </padding>
               -->
               <TableView fx:id="testTable" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="1">
                   <columnResizePolicy>
                       <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                   </columnResizePolicy>
                   <columns>
                       <TableColumn text="TEST NUMBER">
                       <cellValueFactory>
                           <PropertyValueFactory property="testNumber" />
                       </cellValueFactory>
                       </TableColumn>
                       <TableColumn text="TEST NAME">
                           <cellValueFactory>
                           <PropertyValueFactory property="testName" />
                       </cellValueFactory>
                       </TableColumn>
                       <TableColumn text="TEST TIME(ms)">
                           <cellValueFactory>
                           <PropertyValueFactory property="testTime" />
                       </cellValueFactory>
                       </TableColumn>
                       <TableColumn text="BEST MATCH">
                           <cellValueFactory>
                           <PropertyValueFactory property="bestMatch" />
                       </cellValueFactory>
                       </TableColumn>
                   </columns>
                   <items>
                    <!--
                    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                        <TestTableModel testNumber="100" testName="Test1234" testTime="0.34" bestMatch="99"/>
                    </FXCollections>
                    -->
                </items>
               </TableView>
        </GridPane>
    </center>
<stylesheets>
    <URL value="@t-cubed.css" />
</stylesheets>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Use an AnchorPane instead of GridPane.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**How Resizable Layout Works**

The size of resizable items in JavaFX is managed by the layout managers in which the items are placed.

**What you need to do**

For your particular issue, you need to set the GridPane sizing constraints to manage the TableView that you placed in the grid.

See the `GridPane.hgrow` and `GridPane.vgrow` constraints I added on the TableView:

```
<TableView fx:id="testTable" 
           GridPane.columnIndex="0" 
           GridPane.columnSpan="1" 
           GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" 
           GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS"
           GridPane.rowIndex="0">
```

FXML just reflects the Java API, so you could also do the same in Java source as well; i.e. [`GridPane.setHGrow(node, priority)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setHgrow-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.layout.Priority-).  Though, if you are using FXML for your layout, defining the layout constraints in FXML is recommended.

[image: grid]

**Refactored Sample**

I loaded your FXML up in [Scene Builder 2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/sb2download-2177776.html) and set the appropriate constraints and it appears to resize automatically fine when I use the preview functionality of Scene Builder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import t.cubed.fxml.*?>

<BorderPane styleClass="root" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="t.cubed.fxml.FXMLDocumentController">
  <top>
    <MenuBar fx:id="menuBar" styleClass="menu-bar">
      <menus>
        <Menu text="File">
          <items>
            <MenuItem onAction="#handleOpenAction" text="Open" />
            <MenuItem onAction="#handleExitAction" text="Exit" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu text="Edit">
          <items>
            <MenuItem onAction="#handleWeightAction" text="Edit Weights" />
            <MenuItem onAction="#handleFilterAction" text="Edit Filters" />
            <MenuItem onAction="#handleOptionsAction" text="Options" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
      </menus>
    </MenuBar>
  </top>
  <center>
    <GridPane>
       <children>
         <!--
         <padding>
             <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0"/>
         </padding>
         -->
         <TableView fx:id="testTable" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="1" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
           <columnResizePolicy>
             <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
           </columnResizePolicy>
           <columns>
             <TableColumn text="TEST NUMBER">
               <cellValueFactory>
                 <PropertyValueFactory property="testNumber" />
               </cellValueFactory>
             </TableColumn>
             <TableColumn text="TEST NAME">
               <cellValueFactory>
                 <PropertyValueFactory property="testName" />
               </cellValueFactory>
             </TableColumn>
             <TableColumn text="TEST TIME(ms)">
               <cellValueFactory>
                 <PropertyValueFactory property="testTime" />
               </cellValueFactory>
             </TableColumn>
             <TableColumn text="BEST MATCH">
               <cellValueFactory>
                 <PropertyValueFactory property="bestMatch" />
               </cellValueFactory>
             </TableColumn>
           </columns>
           <items>
          <!--
          <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
              <TestTableModel testNumber="100" testName="Test1234" testTime="0.34" bestMatch="99"/>
          </FXCollections>
          -->
        </items>
         </TableView>
       </children>
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints />
         </rowConstraints>
    </GridPane>
  </center>
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@t-cubed.css" />
  </stylesheets>
</BorderPane>
```

**Some Advice**

You are placing the TableView inside a GridPane.  Using a GridPane in your case is a little strange as the GridPane you only place one node in the GridPane.  Just placing the TableView directly in the center of your BorderPane or using a simpler layout parent such as a StackPane would have worked just fine.  But perhaps this is just some cut down version of a more complex UI, so perhaps that is why you have used a GridPane.

**Further Reading**

If you have time, read up on layout in JavaFX in the [Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html), [Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html), [Group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) and [GridPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) javadoc and try this little [layout bounds demo](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1441960) too.

**Additional Questions for Comments**

> mention a StackPane would work, but StackPanes don't seem to have Hgrow and Vgrow?

StackPanes don't need a Hgrow or Vgrow constraints.  Those constraints set [Priorities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Priority.html), which are defined as:

> Enumeration used to determine the grow (or shrink) priority of a given
>   node's layout area when its region has more (or less) space available
>   and multiple nodes are competing for that space.

With a StackPane, all children are layered on top of each other, they don't compete for space, so such growth priority settings for child nodes are not applicable.

Comment: @jewelsea I didn't realize you could drag and drop components inside the hierarchy area. This helps so much, I wish it were easier to learn how to use SceneBuilder.

Comment: You(Or was it @will ? ) mention a StackPane would work, but StackPanes don't seem to have Hgrow and Vgrow?

Answer (score 2):

After some homework, we came up with some qualifying information on FXML containers.  Pretty much for the same reason given above by @user3403469.  In the Scene Builder, there's a long list of '*containers*'.  Imho, only these 9 elements and [Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) qualify as layout container, as they inherit from

<[Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html)> ... parent for all [Pane classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html). While both, Pane and [Control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html) inherit from Region only the Pane child-classes have layout properties.

```
* <AnchorPane>
* <BorderPane>
* <FlowPane>
* <GridPane>
* <StackPane>
* <TextFlow>
* <TilePane>
* <HBox>
* <VBox>
```

You can consider that Control child-classes more or less inherit Events and actions.  Layout like things need to come from the encapsulating region, and the only thing with layout elements available to wrap a 'Control' is-a 'Pane'.

- [javafx.scene.layout.Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html)

These FXML elements would be the bespoke 'layout managers' described in the @jewelsea's answer and elsewhere.

I guess 'Control' containers are still containers in FXML.  It seems that they need to be 'inside' a panel to do good ;-)

***Corrections and comment welcome***.

*related*:

- [Percent width for TableColumn in JavaFX 2.x TableView](http://www.dzone.com/links/r/percent_width_for_tablecolumn_in_javafx_2x_tablev.html)

  - There seems to be a lot of code.  My idea of dynamic resizing is a Zero-tolerance for code to do scaling and resize.  Gee we left that behind in Windows 1.3 *didn't we*?
- [where is the: FXML Specification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008723/where-is-the-fxml-specification)
- [Reference and Guidelines for Dynamic Layout using JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947067/reference-and-guidelines-for-dynamic-layout-using-javafx)