# Resize TableView when stage is maximized

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8, fxml, autoresize

I'm trying to resize two tables in an anchor panel when the stage is maximized to have the same proportion as the default stage sizes.

Now I have that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfJFu.png

But when is maximized there is a lot of space between them:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoFYP.png

I have been searching and I found answers to similar questions saying wrap-in a grid panel but even like that I cannot do it:

[JavaFX tableview resize to fit window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687836/javafx-tableview-resize-to-fit-window)

Someone know what is missing here?

Code fxml:

```
<AnchorPane styleClass="backgroundColor" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="solverassistant.FXMLCompareController">
    <children>
        <AnchorPane prefHeight="270" prefWidth="190.0" styleClass="filterPane" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="40.0">
            <children>
                <Label id="filterLabel" fx:id="filterLabel" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Filter" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0" />
                <TextField id="filterTextField" fx:id="filterTextField" alignment="CENTER" layoutY="20.0" prefWidth="150.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="30.0" />
                <Label id="filterByLabel" fx:id="filterByLabel" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Filter by:" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="70.0" />
                <CheckBox id="solverCheckBox" fx:id="solverCheckBox" layoutY="90.0" selected="true" text="Solver" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="100.0" />
                <CheckBox id="benchmarkCheckBox" fx:id="benchmarkCheckBox" layoutY="110.0" selected="true" text="Benchmark" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="120.0" />
                <CheckBox id="typeCheckBox" fx:id="typeCheckBox" layoutY="130.0" selected="true" text="Solver type" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="140.0" />
                <CheckBox id="timeOutCheckBox" fx:id="timeOutCheckBox" layoutY="150.0" selected="true" text="Time out" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="160.0" />
                <CheckBox id="memoryCheckBox" fx:id="memoryCheckBox" layoutY="170.0" selected="true" text="Memory" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="180.0" />
                <CheckBox id="coresCheckBox" fx:id="coresCheckBox" layoutY="190.0" selected="true" text="Number of cores" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="200.0" />
                <CheckBox id="wholeWordCheckBox" fx:id="wholeWordCheckBox" layoutY="190.0" selected="false" text="Whole word" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="220.0" />
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
        <Button id="reloadButton" fx:id="reloadButton" onAction="#resetAndReloadSolvers" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="190.0" styleClass="button-defaultButton" text="Reset and reload data" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="320.0" />
        <Button id="compareButton" fx:id="compareButton" disable="true" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="150.0" styleClass="button-defaultButton" text="Compare" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="50.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="40.0" />
        <TableView id="allSolversTable" fx:id="allSolversTable" minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="175.0" prefWidth="922.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="245.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="40.0">
            <columnResizePolicy>
                <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
            </columnResizePolicy>
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="colAllSelect" prefWidth="25.0" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="colAllSolver" prefWidth="75.0" text="Solver" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="colAllBenchmark" prefWidth="75.0" text="Benchmark" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="colAllSolverType" prefWidth="75.0" text="Solver type" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="colAllTimeOut" prefWidth="75.0" text="Time out" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="colAllMemory" prefWidth="75.0" text="Memory" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="colAllNumberOfCores" prefWidth="75.0" text="Number of cores" />
            </columns>
        </TableView>
        <TableView id="selectedSolversTable" fx:id="selectedSolversTable" minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="175.0" prefWidth="922.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="50.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="245.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
            <columnResizePolicy>
                <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
            </columnResizePolicy>
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="colSelectedSolver" prefWidth="75.0" text="Solver" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="colSelectedBenchmark" prefWidth="75.0" text="Benchmark" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="colSelectedSolverType" prefWidth="75.0" text="Solver type" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="colSelectedTimeOut" prefWidth="75.0" text="Time out" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="colSelectedMemory" prefWidth="75.0" text="Memory" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="colSelectedNumberOfCores" prefWidth="75.0" text="Number of cores" />
            </columns>
        </TableView>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

All project : github.com/danielcasanovas/SolverAssistant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy thing you could do is just wrap both tables in a `VBox`, let the first table have vertical grow priority set as `ALWAYS` and set `USE_COMPUTE_SIZE` in all the min/pref/max size fields. The second table could be as it was (so only the first one will be resized).

This is the affected part of the FXML file:

```
<VBox spacing="40.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="40.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="245.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="40.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="40.0">
     <children>
          <TableView id="allSolversTable" fx:id="allSolversTable" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
              <columnResizePolicy>
                  <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
              </columnResizePolicy>
              <columns>
                  <TableColumn fx:id="colAllSelect" prefWidth="25.0" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="colAllSolver" prefWidth="75.0" text="Solver" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="colAllBenchmark" prefWidth="75.0" text="Benchmark" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="colAllSolverType" prefWidth="75.0" text="Solver type" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="colAllTimeOut" prefWidth="75.0" text="Time out" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="colAllMemory" prefWidth="75.0" text="Memory" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="colAllNumberOfCores" prefWidth="75.0" text="Number of cores" />
              </columns>
          </TableView>
          <TableView id="selectedSolversTable" fx:id="selectedSolversTable" prefHeight="175.0">
              <columnResizePolicy>
                  <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
              </columnResizePolicy>
              <columns>
                  <TableColumn fx:id="colSelectedSolver" prefWidth="75.0" text="Solver" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="colSelectedBenchmark" prefWidth="75.0" text="Benchmark" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="colSelectedSolverType" prefWidth="75.0" text="Solver type" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="colSelectedTimeOut" prefWidth="75.0" text="Time out" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="colSelectedMemory" prefWidth="75.0" text="Memory" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="colSelectedNumberOfCores" prefWidth="75.0" text="Number of cores" />
              </columns>
          </TableView>
     </children>
  </VBox>
```

Without further changes in your main fxml file, the table should resize properly after any resize of the application.

Comment: For layout problems, usually `VBox` and `HBox` come in handy. Your project is really looking good so far.

Comment: I will do it, thank you so much. Is possible to grow up everything? Like labels in a HBox?

Comment: Usually you have some controls with fixed sizes and just a few resizable controls, but you can set all of the items of some container to grow always, and they will be resized in the same proportion.

Comment: Yes I can see it because for example:
<HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0"AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
<children> 
<Label id="solverLabel" fx:id="solverLabel" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="125.0" text="Solver"/>
<Label id="benchmarkLabel" fx:id="benchmarkLabel" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="125.0" text="Benchmark" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
</children>
</HBox>

don't grow up the labels, as u said I must put it before in another container right?

Comment: Labels don't grow (meaning text font doesn't scale up/down and its fixed witdh doesn't change), and if you set width to use computed size, this width is the minimum required by the string displayed and it doesn't grow either. So wrapping each label in an `HBox`, setting this box to grow always, will work, once you wrap all these boxes inside the outter `HBox`.

Comment: Okay , I got it now, really helpful your explanations!